# Joomla Plugin not running (is installed)

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I have "written" a plugin for Joomla! I say "written" because it is actually someone else's, but it was for Joomla 1.5, and I'm trying to upgrade it to run in Joomla 1.7. However, it's installed and it doesn't want to run. I have tried making it generate an error out of nothing, but it wouldn't give me anything.
I'm not even sure if it is Joomla 1.7 code or not, but I'm hoping you could help with that too.

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined( '_VALID_MOS' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgContentRegisteredTags extends JPlugin
{
    function plgContentRegisteredTags (&$subject, $params)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject,$params);
    }

    function onPrepareContent ( $context, &$article, &$params, $page=0 )
    {
        global $mainframe;
        //if ( !$published ) return true;

        // define the regular expression for the bot
        $regex1 = "#{reg}(.*?){/reg}#s";
        $regex2 = "#{noreg}(.*?){/noreg}#s";

        // perform the replacement
        $article->text = preg_replace_callback(
            $regex1,
            create_function(
                '$matches',
                'global $my;
                if($my->id) return $matches[1];
                return "";'
            ),
            $article->text
        );

        $article->text = preg_replace_callback(
            $regex2,
            create_function(
                '$matches',
                'global $my;
                if(!$my->id) return $matches[1];
                return "";'
            ),
            $article->text
        );

        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: it just doesn't want to run at all (no error, no code execution), even though it is enabled and installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the files name and where is it located (relative to the joomla root) after installation?

Comment: Relatively it's `components/com_registeredtags/helloworld.php`

Comment: I did not work with joomla for some time, but I remember that there are naming conventions for the name of the component file. I think it should be `componentname.php`. So it would be `registeredtags.php` instead of `helloworld.php`.

Comment: Removed it, repackaged it with the new filename, and reinstalled it, but still nothing :/

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you also enable the component? Also I am interested in how you try to access the plugin.

Comment: It is definitely enabled. And from what I understood after Googling this, it should just apply it when you view an Article (which is how I'm trying to execute it)?

Comment: Ok then what is the intend of this component? The usual way to access components is to call them directly via `my.domain/index.php?option=com_registeredtags`. But from your definition it sounds like you want to have a plugin instead of a component?

Comment: My bad, as I said, I'm quite new to this :/ Any idea how to get it to run as a plugin?

Comment: Plugins have another installation manifest (xml) format. You should have a look into the tutorials on creating these files. Another source would be installations of other plugins that you could analyze, as the documentation for new versions is usually rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin-ins in Joomla! are stored in `plugins/plugin-type/plugin_name/` relative to the site root. Components are stored in the `components/` directory.

eg. the pagebreak content plugin is found at 'plugins/content/pagebreak/' and contains the files:

```
plugins/content/pagebreak/pagebreak.php
plugins/content/pagebreak/pagebreak.xml
plugins/content/pagebreak/index.html          // not an active file
```

You can read about [creating a content plugin here.](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin)